# Only sending mail to one of the ticked checkboxes

Tags: php, email, checkbox, phpmailer

I am trying to send mails through phpmailer depending on the values of checkboxes ticked by the user.

This is the code for the check box values :

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <p>Please select departments who should give confirmation</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline clearfix" class="Check1">   
            <div class="col-md-5 checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chmail[]" value="xxx@xxx.com"?> />Head of Operations
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline clearfix" class="Check1">   
            <div class="col-md-5 checkbox">     
                <input type="checkbox" name="chmail[]" value="xxx@xxx.com"?> />Head of Credit
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline clearfix" class="Check1">   
            <div class="col-md-5 checkbox">     
                <input type="checkbox" name="chmail[]" value="xxx@xxx.com"/>Head of CMU
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline clearfix" class="Check1">
            <div class="col-md-5 checkbox">     
                <input type="checkbox" name="chmail[]" value="xxx@xxx.com"/>Head of Finance
            </div><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline clearfix" class="Check1">
            <div class="col-md-5 checkbox">     
                <input type="checkbox" name="chmail[]" value="xxx@xxx.com"/>Head of Risk/Compliance
            </div>      
        </div><br/><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the PHP code to send the email

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{           
    $email_body = $email_body . "<Strong>Form has been sent</strong>";  
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
    $mail->Host       = "xxxx"; 
    $mail->SetFrom('xxxx');
    $mail->Subject    = "xxxx";
    $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);

    if(!empty($_POST['chmail'])){
        foreach($_POST['chmail'] as $selected){
            echo $selected."</br>";
        }
    }
    $mail -> AddAddress($selected); 

    if($mail->Send()) {
        echo "Your form has been submitted succesfully";
    }
    else echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";

    exit;
}
```

But the mail is only going to the last value of the checked checkbox and not all the checked values. Where have I gone wrong / what can I do so that it sends a mail to all the values checked?

Appreciate any suggestions :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should not use addresses that are submitted from the form as it's open to abuse. Put the same list inside your script and only send mail to those preset addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
$mail->AddAddress($selected);
```

and

```
$mail->Send();
```

inside your foreach. That should send an email for each email on your post array.

Comment: Hey sotoz! 

Thanks, that is working, but sending the same person an E-Mail twice. How could I eliminate that?

Comment: @SoumyaRao I don't really know how your emailer class works, but I can assume that you should try instantiating a different object for every email you send with that. Short answer: put `$mail = new PHPMailer();` and the rest $mail vars/methods inside the foreach as well. Of course that is if you want to send 2-3 emails at a time. You should avoid that kind of implementation if you want to send bulk email. Maybe your email class has an example with a loop for sending bulk emails.

Comment: Thank You :) I have actually given different name to the checkboxes and gave seperate if conditions to each one of them and in each if the mail "$mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxx.com");"  and it is working! :) Thanks :)